# Change wifi setup of raspberry pi without screen

Tags: wifi

I did setup a Raspberry pi to serve ssh over a wifi, but the router changed the ip and i cannot update de pi, is there any way to do this without a screen?

Comment: can you scan for devices on your network? nmap or similar.

Comment: In addition to scanning the network or looking at your router's settings, you could also hook a cable up to it and `ssh` in using the Pi's link-local address.

Comment: The pi is setup for connect to router automatically, since router is gone i suppose it is searching...

Comment: Glad you resolved the issue, but I'm curious to know what (if any) changes you made to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` from its *default*? Zeroconf should have saved you, but the key to that is having `/etc/hosts` set up properly (127.0.1.1). Also know that `wpa_supplicant.conf` can hold multiple SSID values.

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to solve this issue:

1. Remove the sdcard
2. Access it using ubuntu machine
3. Modify the wpa_supplicant.conf in /etc/wpa_supplicant with the new setup.
4. Re-insert into rpi.
5. Turn on and wait the ip to show in the router status.

Note that it worked on the second reboot, don't know why it didn't the first.